# Error x[[1]] out of bounds error while trying to knit

Tags: r, knitr

I have the below chunk. It runs fine, gives me output. No errors. (Maybe my logic but nothing that stops the program from running) BUT when I go to knit it I get the following error:

Error in x[[1]] : subscript out of bounds calls:  ... knit_print.default ->normal_print -> print.list Execution halted

```
x <- 0
y <- list()
p <- ncol(data)

for (i in 2:p){
  x <- 0 
  
  tbl <- table(data[,i]) 
    res <- cbind(tbl,round(prop.table(tbl)*100,2)) 
    colnames(res) <- c('Count','Percentage') 
    print(res)
    
    g <- length(which(as.character(data[,i])=="Other")) 
    h <- length(which(as.character(data[,i])=="Don't know"))
    j <- length(which(as.character(data[,i])=="Refuse to answer"))
    k <- length(which(as.character(data[,i])=="Don't Know/Refuse to answer"))
    m <- length(which(as.character(data[,i])=="Don't Know/Refuse to Answer"))
    r <- length(which(data[,i]!="NA"))
    
    if (r == 0) {
      next
    }
 
  x <- g+h+j+k+m+x
  
   if (x == 0) {
      next
    }
  
r <- length(which(data[,i]!="NA"))
  
      if ((x/r) >= .1) {            
    names(data[, i, drop = FALSE])
    y <- c(y,names(data)[i])
      }    
}    

z <- length(which(data[,37:41]==1))
t <- length(which(data[,40:41]==1))
#if ((t/z) >= .1) {
    #names(data[, 37, drop = FALSE])
  #  y <- c(y,names(data)[37])
#}

v <- length(which(data[,45:49]==1))
b <- length(which(data[,48:49]==1))
#if ((b/v) >= .1) {
   # names(data[, 45, drop = FALSE])
   # y <- c(y,names(data)[45])
#}    
y
```

x is a counter I use to count the number of specific replies to questions.
y is an empty list to capture the column names of columns reaching a specific threshold.
So I count the replies in each column and determine which are flagged for further review.
The program runs. But will not knit. I have some lines #commented out on purpose

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Do you have more chunks than just that one in the document?

Comment: I do, but the error states line 233 which is this chunk's starting point.

Comment: If the chunk runs fine by itself that means, that either you need to clear your environment, or that something in the chunks beforehand is wrong.

Comment: Every chunk runs fine. I cleared the environment and still nothing. Thank you though for the suggestions.

Comment: You need to show us what `data` looks like at the start of the chunk.  You can do this by printing the result of `dput(head(data))` in a chunk just before this one, and commenting out (or temporarily deleting) the rest of the document.

Comment: structure(list(SbjNum = c(109756715L, 109756716L, 109756717L, 
109756935L, 109756936L, 109756937L), elpt_q1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes", "Don't know", "Refuse to answer"
), class = "factor"), elpt_q2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("In this constituency", "In another constituency", 
"Not registered", "Don't Know/Refuse to answer"), class = "f

Comment: Any other suggestions?